# Import files from computer connected on network and compress them

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating File Compressor in C# and i have to add the functionality to add files from the computer connected on LAN. And i have no idea how to implement that basically i insert every file in a list and at the end will compress them and zip them.

I need help regarding **how can i transfer those selected files from other computer connected on network**? So that i can zip them at the end?

Comment: Can you just adress them like local files, but by UNC? (\\computername\c$\path\filename.ext)

Comment: Like local files, basically i have to import those selected files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using a restricted project type (WinRT, Universal Windows App, etc.) you could just use network shares. The `System.IO` namespace can handle them just fine. All you need to do is use the `\\[IP or machine name]\[share name]` addressing.

Note that network shares need to be configured separately - your app likely won't be able to enable a share on a remote system.

Comment: am using windows form application and will you please elaborate who can i include those files using System.IO?

Comment: @AashirJaved Just treat them as a file location, really. There's nothing else to it. Example: `File.Open(@"\\myNetworkShare\Folder\File.txt")` - this assumes that `myNetworkShare` has been configured and is accessible, of course. As for setting up network shares - well, this is something you can find in Google very easily - the Windows OS makes setting them up easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a symbolic link (this can easily be done through powershell) and then reference that link.